# How to take large file uploads from users the right way

Tags: forms, uploads

I'm using gravity forms to take mp3 submissions but doing it like that seems to be extremely intensive on my site especially when multiple people are doing it one time and streaming the content aswell. Is using amazon cloudfront to stream the media going to make a big difference and what's a good technique for taking uploads in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *right* way is entirely dependent on what limitations you want to place on your users.

WordPress ships with a library called [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/).  This is what powers the multi-file uploader in core, and it's available to create your own upload tools as well.  The beneficial feature of plupload is the ability to chunk files on the client side before uploading them.

Essentially, plupload lets you split large files up on the client and upload much smaller files to the server.  As a result, your server is more responsive (doesn't have to handle very long requests).  On the downside, these features are difficult to implement in older browsers (read: Internet Explorer) and require stand-ins (read: Flash or Silverlight).

*Using* plupload isn't a WordPress question, so if you go this route I encourage you to open new questions on SO.

Comment: I tried using the plugin for it [link]http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wplupload/ but it says it has an invalid header. Is plupload a core feature of wordpress?

Comment: Not really. Plupload is a standalone JavaScript library for handling uploads, but it *ships* with WordPress and is bundled in core by default.